# wxPython build menus on MacBook

Tags: macos, wxpython

On a MacBook running MacOS Mojave 10.14.6, Python 3.7.4 and wxPython 4.0.6 I can't get menus to work when creating a GUI.  Here's the code I'm using.

```
def basicGUI(self):
    menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
    fileButton = wx.Menu()
    exitItem = fileButton.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'Exit', 'status msg..')

    menuBar.Append(fileButton, 'File')
    menuBar.Append(fileButton, 'Edit')

    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Quit, exitItem)

    self.SetTitle('Epic Window')
    self.Show(True)
```

Creating the frame and panel is all OK.  Any assistance would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't own a mac, but running your code on windows produces an assertion error because you're adding the menu named 'fileButton' twice. If you comment out the line `menuBar.Append(fileButton, 'Edit')` your example should run. If you want to create an edit menu, don't reuse the file menu instance, create a new `wx.Menu()` instance.

```
import wx


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.basicGUI()

    def basicGUI(self):
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()

        fileButton = wx.Menu()
        editmenu = wx.Menu()

        exitItem = wx.MenuItem(fileButton, wx.ID_EXIT, "Exit")
        edit_item = wx.MenuItem(editmenu, wx.ID_EDIT, "Edit")

        fileButton.Append(exitItem)
        editmenu.Append(edit_item)

        menuBar.Append(fileButton, 'File')
        menuBar.Append(editmenu, 'Edit')

        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Quit, id=wx.ID_EXIT)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_edit, id=wx.ID_EDIT)

        self.SetTitle('Epic Window')
        self.CenterOnScreen(wx.BOTH)
        self.Show(True)

    def Quit(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def on_edit(self, event):
        with wx.MessageDialog(self, "You clicked edit", "Caption", wx.ICON_INFORMATION) as dialog:
            dialog.ShowModal()


app = wx.App()
frame = Frame(parent=None)
app.MainLoop()
```

**Side Note:** 
     It's helpful if you post a runnable example of your problem instead of just the excerpted method so we can see the problem in its full context instead of having to assume what the rest of your program looks like.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the suggestion.  Alas it didn't work.  All I got was the frame, no menu or buttons.

Comment: @GrahamHansen I reformatted the code to explicitly create menu items, see if that works

Comment: No go, same result.  can't put the screenshot of frame into this edit (sri)